# return something without the single quote

Tags: python, list, return

So I have a function that looks like this:

```
self=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

def evens(self):
    evens=[]
    for item in self:
        if item%2==0:
            evens.append(item)
    return 'intlist({})'.format(evens)
```

I want to return to look like this:

```
intlist[2,4,6,8]
```

but instead I'm getting this:

```
'intlist[2,4,6,8]'
```

how can I get the return without the single quote?

This function is actually inside a class I'm writing.

Comment: You are asking for a formatted string as a result, so that's what you're getting. Is `intlist` a function you have defined elsewhere in your code? Perhaps you should change the last line of your code to something like: `return intlist('{}'.format(evens))`, or even just `return intlist(evens)`.

Comment: @ChidGilovitz `intlist` isn't defined, he can't do that.

Comment: `self` is usually used to represent an instance of a class. Better pick a different name for your `list`

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much.

Comment: Are you seeing the quoted string in an interactive console? (Because your code should not return one) See if `print(it)` prints what you expected.

Comment: @Leb, You're right - I was assuming it probably was defined somewhere else in his code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running it in the REPL?

You should `print()` the result. The default is for the REPL to display the `repr` of the result.

NB. see my comment about using `self` as a variable

```
>>> self=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> 
>>> def evens(self):
...     evens=[]
...     for item in self:
...         if item%2==0:
...             evens.append(item)
...     return 'intlist({})'.format(evens)
... 
>>> evens(self)
'intlist([2, 4, 6, 8])'
>>> print(evens(self))
intlist([2, 4, 6, 8])
```

Comment: REPL is the (Python) shell. I have to admit that I did not know that. Maybe I'm not alone. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop

Answer (score 1):

print function is ok

python3:

```
>>> self=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> print('intlist({})'.format(self))
intlist([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```